# State taxes for nonresident international PhD students in Massachusetts?

Tags: united-states, taxes, massachusetts

Do I have to file state taxes (in addition to federal taxes) as a nonresident international PhD student in Massachusetts?

Answer (score 3):

Depends. On what? [Here](http://www.mass.gov/dor/individuals/filing-and-payment-information/guide-to-personal-income-tax/residency-status.html) is all the info (Mass dept. of revenue). In the university, you should ask the international students' office for guidance on taxes, they probably have an on-site adviser. The tax preparation program usually used by the international students is CINTAX (now called [GlacierTax](https://www.glaciertax.com/)) and you should ask for credentials from the international students' office.

If they don't provide neither consultations nor access to Glacier - seek a local tax adviser who's experienced with foreigners, there's plenty of those in MA.